# Hide preview widget in QColumnView?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5

I want to hide the preview widget that is displayed as the last column even when it has no children. I've looked everywhere on the internet and umpteen number of users didn't want the preview widget to be added as the last column all the time.

- [QColumnView is rolled to empty column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370223/qcolumnview-is-rolled-to-empty-column)
- [Qt: is it possible to turn off previewWidget in QColumnView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38834428/qt-is-it-possible-to-turn-off-previewwidget-in-qcolumnview)
- [Is it possible to remove the preview widget from a qt QColumnView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419185/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-preview-widget-from-a-qt-qcolumnview)
- http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/59917-Columnview-removing-final-column
- http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/22566-How-to-turn-off-this-annoying-feature-of-QColumnView

What's more pathetic here is, No solution has been offered till now [From 2010]. Is there any way to get rid of this annoying behaviour? If not, shouldn't the Qt developers provided this option at-least in Qt5? Let me know if I miss something here.

Note: I've tried the **possible** suggested solutions and none of them worked

- Setting the column width to 0 - **Failed**
- Return False for createColumn - createColumn is not at all called when the preview widget is shown

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do it. In `qcolumnview.cpp` in `QColumnViewPrivate::createColumn()`, you have (comments are mine):

```
 if (model->hasChildren(index)) { // Create column when there are children to display
    view = q->createColumn(index);
    q->connect(view, SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)),
               q, SLOT(_q_clicked(QModelIndex)));
} else { // Create column when there are no more children => the column will show the preview widget
    if (!previewColumn)
        setPreviewWidget(new QWidget(q)); // Indirectly create previewColumn
    view = previewColumn;
    view->setMinimumWidth(qMax(view->minimumWidth(), previewWidget->minimumWidth()));
}
```

If you want to change the behavior of the QColumnView so that the preview widget it not always displayed you will have to contribute by fixing it yourself in Qt code and pushing to Qt git repo, or create a suggestion in Qt  [bug tracker](https://bugreports.qt.io) and wait for someone nice to fix it.

Comment: Or write your own column-view class that has exactly the behaviour you want.